# regex invalid expression nothing to repeat

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-negation

I am trying to remove everything except '+' from a string

I am using this:

```
phone = re.sub(r'[^+]', '', cleaned_data['phone_number'])
```

i tried this too:

```
phone = re.sub(r'[^\+]', '', cleaned_data['phone_number'])
```

It fails with 'invalid expression'

EDIT: using a debugger if found the error is located in these lines

```
phone_patterns = [r'^0\d{9}$', r'^\+33\d{9}$']
        for phone_pattern in phone_patterns:
            if re.match(phone, phone_pattern):
                .....
```

stack_trace:
Traceback:

```
File "/path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/path/request_quote/views.py" in new
  12.         if formset.is_valid():
File "/path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in is_valid
  277.         err = self.errors
File "/path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in errors
  259.             self.full_clean()
File "/path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in full_clean
  297.             self._errors.append(form.errors)
File "/path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  117.             self.full_clean()
File "/path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  273.         self._clean_form()
File "/path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  299.             self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "/path/request_quote/forms.py" in clean
  56.         QuoteForm.COUNTRY_VALIDATORS[country](self, cleaned_data)
File "/path/request_quote/forms.py" in validate_fr
  102.             if re.match(phone, phone_pattern):
File "/path/lib/python2.7/re.py" in match
  137.     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
File "/path/lib/python2.7/re.py" in _compile
  242.         raise error, v # invalid expression

Exception Type: error at /en/request_quote/new/
Exception Value: nothing to repeat
```

EDIT:
the error comes from the '+' at the beginning should be escaped but how ?

EDIT2:
Awfully stupid but i did

```
re.match(string,pattern)
```

instead of

```
re.match(pattern,string)
```

Comment: If you are trying to remove everything, why not just `phone = '+'`?

Comment: Anyway, your code works. Post the full traceback and make sure this is the code you are running.

Comment: "something like this"? No, that new edit still won't throw the error you're reporting (it will however return `"+"` for the input `"+1234"`). So won't you please, please, post the actual regex you're using?

Comment: fixed typed \D instead of \d

Comment: You still haven't included the actual pattern you're using. The string `r"[^\+\d]"` compiles perfectly well into a regex object.

Answer (score 2):

try this regex for phone number:

`/^[0-9\+]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}$/`

.

it will accept:

1) Optional + at the start

2) numbers

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
>>> import string
>>> phone = "+1729"
>>> "".join(x for x in phone if x in string.digits)
'1729'
```